# Calling function and variables from other files in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have two files

app.js and funcs.js

in app.js i have following code

```
require('./funcs.js');
```

in funcs.js
i have following code

```
var TYPE_KEEPER = 1;
var TYPE_USER   = 0;

function getBooking(bookingId, callback)
{   
   // some function here.
}
```

Now when i run app.js, and call TYEP_KEEPER, It gives me error

```
ReferenceError: TYPE_DRIVER is not defined
```

How can i define all constants in other function. and also how can i call the function in app.js , the very function defined in funcs.js

Comment: There's many ways to do this, for instance just returning an object from the funcs.js file, and doing `var stuff_from_func = require('./funcs.js');` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a possible solution to your problem, even though it is not the only one available (as an example, you could export a factory of objects in place of what is below).

In the first file, you have to export your stuff as it follows:

```
module.exports = {
    "TYPE_KEEPER": 1,
    "TYPE_USER": 0,
    "getBooking": function (bookingId, callback) { /* some function here. */ }
}
```

Somewhere, you can use them as it follows:

```
var stuff = require('path_to_the_file_above');
console.log(stuff["TYPE_KEEPER"]);
stuff.getBooking();
```

Comment: module.exports = {
    
    EVENT_CONNECTED               = "cityConnected";
tried this and giving error /var/www/html/Constants.js:3
app-0 (err):     EVENT_CONNECTED               = "cityConnected";
app-0 (err):         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
app-0 (err): SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: hi, if i want to get something in return var xx = stuff.getBooking(); how do i return data back in function?

Comment: By using the *return* statement in your function. What's wrong?

Comment: returns nothing, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341825/getting-response-of-a-function-defined-in-another-file-in-node-js